# Showing that the generator of the semigroup $(e^{tA})_{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ is $A$.

Tags: operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

[image]

Hello. I am studying semigroup theory. In "one-parameter semigroups of positive operators"  it is stated that $A$ is the generator. Why?

Given the definition, it should be
$$Af=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^{hA}f-f}{h}$$
but $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{e^{hA}f-f}{h}=0$ for all $f$

Why is $A$ the generator?

Comment: ...No, $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{hA} f - f}{h}$ *is* $Af$. Subtracting $f$ kills the $n=0$ term and then sending $h \to 0$ after dividing by $h$ kills all the other terms.

Comment: certain. I just saw it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for IAN

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ (e^{hA}-I)f}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(hA+(h^2A^2)/2!+\cdots)f}{h}=Af$$